# Сложение нескольких функция между собой. Python. Telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать бота телеграмм, для личных расчетов. По задумке хочу отправлять числовые значения боту по очереди, а затем прописать в коде, чтобы они складывались (вычитались, умножались, делились) между собой и выводились в виде числа, единым результатом. Уже голову сломал с этой конкатенацией.. Буду признателен если укажите на мои ошибки..

Код:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN, threaded=False)

user_dict = {}  

class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.benzin = name
        self.rashod = None
        self.kolkm = None
        self.kolpoe = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Цена за литр 92 (руб.):')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_benzin_step)


def process_benzin_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        benzin = message.text
        user = User(benzin)
        if not benzin.isdigit():
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Значение может быть только числом!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_benzin_step)
            return
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Расход на 100 км (л.):')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_rashod_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ошибка')


def process_rashod_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        rashod = message.text
        user = User(rashod)
        if not rashod.isdigit():
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Значение может быть только числом!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_rashod_step)
            return
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Количество км (за 1 поездку)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_kolkm_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ошибка')


def process_kolkm_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        kolkm = message.text
        user = User(kolkm)
        if not kolkm.isdigit():
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Значение может быть только числом!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_kolkm_step)
            return
        user_dict[chat_id] = user
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Кол-во поездок (в месяц)')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_kolpoe_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ошибка')


def process_kolpoe_step(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        kolpoe = message.text
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        if not kolpoe.isdigit():
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Значение может быть только числом!')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_kolpoe_step)
            return
        itog = user.benzin + user.rashod + user.kolkm + user.kolpoe
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, itog)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ошибка')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Как бы не пытался исправить, всегда выдает примерно похожие ошибки:

```
..line 83, in process_kolpoe_step
itog = user.benzin + user.rashod + user.kolkm + user.kolpoe
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

синим, черным и красным по серому написано, что нельзя складывать строку с None.

```
print(f"user.benzin: {user.benzin}")
print(f"user.rashod: {user.rashod}")
print(f"user.kolkm: {user.kolkm}")
print(f"user.kolpoe: {user.kolpoe}")
itog = user.benzin + str(int(user.rashod or 0) + int(user.kolkm or 0) + int(user.kolpoe or 0))
```

Будет проще если по умолчанию все переменные пользователя которые надо складывать будут равны 0.

```
fields = ['rashod', 'kolkm', 'kolpoe']

itog = user.benzin + str(sum(getattr(user, x, 0) for x in fields)))
```